# How to show values as a string, what got from database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show strings instead of values, that is inserted to database.
Table1:

```
name | type_id

test1 | 1
test2 | 2
```

Table2:

```
name | types

test3 | 1,2
test4 | 2,1
```

And when I print it, I want to replace 1,2 and 2,1 with test1, test2 and test2, test1 (names from table one)

Comment: Fix your data model!  You should not be storing numbers as strings.  You should have properly declared foreign key relationships.  You want a junction/association table with one row per name/type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables to `group by table2.name` and use `group_concat()`:

```
select
  t2.name, group_concat(t1.name order by find_in_set(t1.type_id, t2.types)) nametypes
from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
on concat(',', t2.types, ',') like concat('%', type_id, '%')
group by t2.name
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5yc9e8mjzjLyYKc8WnRkMg/0).
Results:

```
| name  | nametypes   |
| ----- | ----------- |
| test3 | test1,test2 |
| test4 | test2,test1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a horrible data format.  Here are some reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Columns should contain one value.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL has pretty lousy functionality for managing strings.

The proper table format would be:

table2

```
   table_2    name    type_id
   1          test3   1
   2          test3   2
   3          test4   2
   4          test4   1
```

Then you would simply do:

```
select t2.name, group_concat(t1.name order by t2.id)
from table2 t2 join
     table1 t1
     on t2.type_id = t1.type_id
group by t2.name
```